# grep return only one match per line

Tags: grep

example file :

```
foobar random text foobar random text foobar
text
text
text
```

If I use `grep` and search for the word `foobar`, how can I prevent `grep` to return me the first line 3 times, because it founds 3 times `foobar` ? What I would like to have is only one return per line, even if the word has been found multiple times on the line

Comment: What command do you use? `grep -o`?

Comment: I use `grep -in`, to ignore case and to get the line number where the word has been found

Comment: But your example shows extracted text. Do you want just the search term, or the whole line?

Comment: I want the entire line. In my example, I said it founds 3 times foobar, not that it was returning it. Everytime I found the correct word, I print the whole line (that's why I need it only one time when it's on the same line)

Answer (score 0):

Simple ***awk*** alternative:

```
awk '/\<foobar\>/{print NR,"foobar"}' file
```

The output(for your exemplary input):

```
1 foobar
```

---

`\<` and `\>` mean *word boundaries*

`NR` - contains current line number

---

With ***perl***:

```
perl -ne 'print $.," ",$1,"\n" if /\b(foobar)\b/' file
```

The output:

```
1 foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.txt`:

```
foobar random text foobar random text foobar
text
text
text
```

command:

```bash
grep foobar file.txt
```

output:

```bash
foobar random text foobar random text foobar
```

`grep` version: **GNU grep 3.4**
So, the line containing `foobar` is shown only once. If you see more lines, include option `-n` to see the line numbers of each output line, i.e.,

```bash
grep -n foobar file.txt
```